# set Karate-config.js values in feature

Tags: karate

How can I set values in karate-config.js in a feature?
Ex: I create a cat in one of my features and I would like to put this id in karate-config.js in the value named catId

`var config = {
    env: env,
    baseUrl: 'blabla.com',
    catId: 'put id here'
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is bad practice to expect a feature to depend on some other feature. Or think of it this way - if you skip a feature (using code-commenting, tags etc), it should not cause some other feature to fail.

So Karate does not support *updating* anything set via `karate-config.js` by default.

That said, refer to the [doc on "hooks"](https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks), specifically the `karate.callSingle()` method - which may be the answer you are looking for.